# how to pass an object as a prop in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend

I cant quite figure out how I am supposed to pass an object as a prop when using useState in Next JS.

I have a lorem ipsum generator that I created in javascript functions. I have a component called `Paragraphs` that houses it. I need to pass in two properties,

1. a number of paragraphs.
2. a sentence length.

The paragraph length is set by a text input where the user types in 1-10. The sentence length is set by radio buttons.

The problem I am running into is that when you input any value, the setState gets called (intentional) and it works, the problem is, it constantly works. I want to only have it update when I click my "Adventure" button to generate the data. I am unsure how to set those values to an set them as object property values and pass the object then.

Below is my code for the fields

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'


import Paragraph from '../components/ipsum/Paragraph.js'


export default function rpgIpsum() {

    const [paragraphNumber, setParagraphNumber] = useState(5)
    const [sentenceLength, setSentenceLength] = useState(5)
    const [data, setData ] = useState({
        outputProps: {
            paragraphNumber: 5,
            sentenceLength: 5
        }
    })

    return (
        <div>
            {data.outputProps.paragraphNumber}
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-2 d-sm-none d-xs-none d-md-block d-none">
                        {/* <img src="public/images/Bard.jpg" alt="Lorem Ipsum Bard!" className="img-fluid" /> */}
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-10">
                        <h2>Looking to add some fun to your filler text?</h2>
                        <h5>Let's Spiffy up your copy with some RPG inspired Lorem Ipsum!</h5>

                        <div className="form-container">
                            <p>First, select how many paragraphs you want.  
                                <input 
                                    type="text" 
                                    name="para" 
                                    value={paragraphNumber} 
                                    className="para-box" 
                                    required 
                                    onInput={
                                        event => setParagraphNumber(parseInt(event.target.value))
                                    }
                                />
                                <small id="para-box-help" className="form-text text-muted">(Max of 10)</small>
                            </p>
                            <p>Next, select the length of the sentences</p>
                            <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <input 
                                    className="form-check-input" 
                                    type="radio" 
                                    name="sentences" 
                                    value="3" 
                                    required 
                                    onInput={
                                        event => setSentenceLength(parseInt(event.target.value))
                                    }
                                /> 
                                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="inlineRadio1">Short</label>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <input 
                                    className="form-check-input" 
                                    type="radio" 
                                    name="sentences" 
                                    value="5" 
                                    required 
                                    onInput={
                                        event => setSentenceLength(parseInt(event.target.value))
                                    }
                                />
                                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="inlineRadio2">Medium</label>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <input 
                                    className="form-check-input" 
                                    type="radio" 
                                    name="sentences" 
                                    value="7" 
                                    required 
                                    onInput={
                                        event => setSentenceLength(parseInt(event.target.value))
                                    }
                                />
                                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="inlineRadio3">Long</label>
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary"   
                                    onClick={ event => "what do i do here?" ))}
                                >Adventure!</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12">
                        <hr />
                            <Paragraph paragraphNumber={data.outputProps.paragraphNumber} sentenceLength={data.outputProps.sentenceLength}/>
                                                
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but do you want to make it so that your Paragraph component *only* updates when you click the submit button?

Comment: That is correct @iamkneel, I want to essentially store those values in an object with two properties, for example `{paragraphs: 2, sentenceLength: 3}` and then update that object from the form when a button is clicked, thus updating the props and generating a new ipsum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'd do is refactor the input functionality into a separate component and use a function prop to pass the input data to an outer component that also contains the `Paragraph` component, like so:

```
// rpgIpsum.js
export default function rpgIpsum() {
  const [settings, setSettings] = useState({
    paragraphNumber: 5,
    sentenceLength: 5
  });

  return (
    <>
      <ParagraphInput onSubmit={setSettings} />
      <Paragraph {...settings} />
    </>
  );
}

// ParagraphInput.js
export default function ParagraphInput({ onSubmit }) {
  const [paragraphNumber, setParagraphNumber] = useState(5);
  const [sentenceLength, setSentenceLength] = useState(5);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* ... */}
      <button
        type="submit"
        onClick={() => onSubmit({paragraphNumber, sentenceLength})}
      >Adventure!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

That way, `settings` in `rpgIpsum` is only updated when the button inside `ParagraphInput` is pressed, and not on every change of the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a parent component and lift the state of your components up to that parent component. Or you can use Redux for your state management, it would make it easier for you to pass data to your components.

Comment: im familiar with how I would leverage this in VueJS, for example I would just set a payload to update the prop passed on a button click, thats somewhat what I am trying to replicate, however Im not sure what the syntax would look like

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).